# Customize XFCE4 Applications Menu applet stylesheet

Tags: css, menu, customization, xfce

I am curious to where the XFCE4 Applications Menu applet directory is located. I would like to edit the applet so that vertical text on top of a graphic is displayed alongside the left hand side of the applet (kind of like Windows 95). Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure you can achieve this only with rcstyle (gtk2) or css (gtk3, since 4.13). You can give it a try on runtime with GtkInspector, but I think you'll end up playing with its [source code](https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/tree/plugins/applicationsmenu)

Comment: Okay, thanks AndreLDM :)